# javascript/php rounding

Tags: javascript, php, rounding

I have the product price 1.83 and tax 9% -->0.1647. The total price should be 2.00.
I want that value to be with 2 decimals on rounding to be 0.17. I tried

```
(ceil(($item['price'] * $tax['percent'] / 100)*100)/100)
```

and it works only for this price but with the same method, the product price with 3.67  with tax 9% -->0.3303 becomes 0.34. total is 4.01 and i need this to be 4.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like you have unclear limits. Why exactly should 1.9947 be rounded up to 2.00 instead of 1.99?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `round()` on the price added with the final computed tax.

```php
php > $price = 1.83; $tax = 9; echo round($price + ceil(($price * $tax / 100)*100)/100);
2
php > $price = 3.67; $tax = 9; echo round($price + ceil(($price * $tax / 100)*100)/100);
4
```

**Edit**

```php
php > $price = 1.83; $tax = 9; $final = round($price + ceil(($price * $tax / 100)*100)/100);
php > echo "Price: $price, Tax:" . ($final - $price);
Price: 1.83, Tax:0.17

php > $price = 3.67; $tax = 9; $final = round($price + ceil(($price * $tax / 100)*100)/100);
php > echo "Price: $price, Tax:" . ($final - $price);
Price: 3.67, Tax:0.33
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wouldn't work. I need the individual values of price and vat, AFTER their correction as i am saving those in the database and not the total. Thus, when i add them, they should be correct without additional rounding!
e.g. on first example i would save 1.83 as the price and vat 0.17 (corrected from 0.16)
On second 3.67 price, and vat corrected to 0.33 instead of 0.34

Comment: @ChrysostomosPogiatzis Hi again, I had edited my answer and now does exactly what your describe. The price and the corrected tax are individual values now.

Comment: The answer given here is correct as well as incorrect depending on more clearer information given by @Jon. ceil (ceiling) represents a floating value and will round the number of 1.9947 to 2, logic however says this value is incorrect and might return undesirable values, if this is what Jon requires then this is 100% correct, hence my upvote.

Comment: @AndreOosthuizen I used `ceil()` because I did not want to change the original algorithm he had made, unless there's something wrong with it?

Comment: @Jon.Frenchtoast I like your approach but i don't think it solves the issue. 
round should have 2 decimals. You use NONE so it rounds to 2, or 4 correctly... what happens with a price that's 1.51? It'll become 2 <-- wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you the correct tax you are looking for. If you are expecting more than 4 decimals then you may need to make the `.toFixed()` recurive.

**JaveScript**:

```
(+((($item['price'] * $tax['percent'] / 100)).toFixed(3)).toFixed(2)
```

**PHP**:

```
number_format(number_format($item['price'] * $tax['percent']/100, 3, '.', ""), 2, '.', "")
```

or

```
round(round(($item['price'] * $tax['percent']/100), 3), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the number_format and specify the decimals as in -

```
$sum = 1234.9874   
$total = "number_format($sum, 2, '.', '');
```

2 is the decimal points that you can change to however many decimal points you like. the dot is the cents separator, this can be changed to comma as well.

You can [Read More Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) on the number format constructor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Andre. Your answer is off subject and not what the question implies. The question is related to rounding the sum and the individual values to match without the -+1 cent

Comment: @Angelos, I disagree as the number format also rounds the number correctly as per my link to the PHP documentation - "It's not explicitly documented; number_format also rounds:" with sample given. I tested this and the rounding is done correctly. OP asked for the number to be rounded AND a 2 decimal value, which number format gives in one go.

Comment: I do however agree with Jay's comment that the the number 1.9947 cannot be rounded to 2.00 as the value 4 does not constitute a round off as yet, only from 5 i.e. 1.9957 will be rounded to 2.00 as to where 1.9947 will be rounded to 1.99